# iphone audio app development

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm a beginning developer who has done a bit of audio work. I was just wondering what is the approach to starting to work with audio on the iphone platform.

I envision this as somehow getting a vector of numbers which represent the samples in an audio track. Then programmatically running algorithms on that vector (or array) that would act as filters or other DSP functions.

I could be totally off in my thinking, but I guess that is the point of my question. How do I get to this point where I'm able to start coding the audio on a very low level in the iphone environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aurioTouch example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) from the Apple site may be of use. The example analysis the audio data and displays the frequency domain of it.

From the example;

> The code uses: the AU Remote IO audio
>   unit to get the audio input and copy
>   it to the output the UI presents: -
>   Oscilloscope view of the audio - time
>   domain - frequency domain - Scrolling
>   sonogram of the audio - Mute button to
>   turn on/off the play through

Answer (score 0):

Both the Audio Queue and the Audio Unit Remote IO APIs will allow you to get a vector of numbers representing the mic input, or play a vector of numbers (PCM samples) to the speaker output.  RemoteIO is a slightly more complicated APU, but it allows a lower latency (shorter vectors).

You can't get a vector of numbers in real-time for the currently playing iTunes music on a stock OS device.  However there are new APIs for getting and processing the track data in non-real-time.